# Identifying the Correct Commission Rate- MS Excel Challenge

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table of Item Numbers, Prices and the corresponding Commission Rates laid out like this...

```
   A     |    B    |    C    |    D    |    E    |   F   |  G   |  H   |  I
XL-9000  |  $6500  |  $5500  |  $4500  |  $3500  |  10%  |  8%  |  6%  |  5%
```

If the sale of the XL-9000 was made for $6500 or more, then the salesperson qualifies for the 10% commission.

How can I write a formula which selects the appropriate commission from the table given the item number and sale price?

Help is truly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the data is in row 1 and that you were going to put the actual sale price in cell `J1` then the following formula could go in `K1` to determine the appropriate commission amount:

```
=IF(J1>B1,F1,IF(J1>C1,G1,IF(J1>D1,H1,IF(J1>E1,I1,"No commission"))))
```

I suspect that you are going to have a whole sheet of correlated commissions, with the sell prices located somewhere else.  For that you would have to include some `VLOOKUP` references and possibly some more nested `IF` statements to make it function automatically, but this should get you started.

Comment: Thanks, I did like you suggested and brought the commission table information in with a series of vlookups...

Answer (score 0):

I've made one very rather lengthy formula which will do that:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("F"&MATCH(K1,$A$1:$A$5,0)&":I"&MATCH(K1,$A$1:$A$5,0)),1,IFERROR(MATCH(L1,INDIRECT("B"&MATCH(K1,$A$1:$A$5,0)&":E"&MATCH(K1,$A$1:$A$5,0)),-1),0)+1),0)`

The thing is that it's relying a lot on `MATCH(K1,$A$1:$A$5,0)` which gives the row of the Item Number you are looking for. If I substitute those by XX in the formula, it becomes: You will need to change `$A$5` to the correct reference to match your table, and there are 4 instances.

`=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("F"&XX&":I"&XX,1,IFERROR(MATCH(L1,INDIRECT("B"&XX&":E"&XX,0)),-1),0)+1),0)`

Here, `K1` is the cell of the item product and `L1` is the sales volume. Below is an example:

[image: Snapshot]

(Open in new tab or new window for larger version)